# Will the new NetworkManager 0.9 be included in 11.10 and what features will it bring?

Tags: network-manager, 11.10

Today I read that the 0.9 version of Network Manager which comes with "ton of great changes" (Which actually does not say much ;) ) was released so I was wondering if it will be coming with Ubuntu 11.10 and if yes what features does it bring since they are not mentioned in the main web page of the network manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Release process Network Manager v. 0.9](http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager/ReleaseProcess)
>
> This major new release is planned for March 2011. It's most significant feature is a huge simplification of the configuration model, bringing benefits to both users and developers. The most significant feature for users will be richer and more capable network control and configuration applets for GNOME 3.0's GNOME Shell and Ubuntu's Indicator system, and full support for fast user switching and shared computers.
>
> For developers, the 0.9 release merges the User and System settings services into NetworkManager itself, allowing simpler client applets and streamlined configuration management. As a result NetworkManager's D-Bus API is also much simpler, and further API convenience methods will be provided for common client operations like creating a new connection from a scanned access point, filtering existing connections for a specific device, etc.
>
> For more detailed information on the architectural changes in the 0.9 release, see [NetworkManager/ApiSimplify](http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager/ApiSimplify).

Besides the list at the last link [NetworkManager D-Bus Reference Manual](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/migrating-to-09/ref-migrating.html) also states NetworkManager now supports Intel WiMAX mobile broadband devices.

And to answer your question: the Oneiric packages list shows version `0.9.0-0ubuntu1` for [network manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/net/network-manager).

Comment: Already used my votes but for this very complete answer I will +1 when I get my votes back. Thanks again Rinzwind for another great answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be correct also to say that you'll not be able to import your old network configurations into the new Network Manager because the structure is changed and it's not compatible with the old gconf style configs.